# SendMessage fails to set ToolTip window

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip, sendmessage

I have created my own custom control and here i want to set this custom control as ToolTip for other controls. So i have added codes to set the custom control as ToolTip through sendMessage through below code,

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    Dictionary<IntPtr, Component> m_tools;
    TOOLINFO m_toolInfo;

    public MyControl()
    {
        m_tools = new Dictionary<IntPtr, Component>();
        m_toolInfo = new TOOLINFO();
    }

    string myTipText;

    public string MyTipText
    {
        get
        {
            return myTipText;
        }
        set
        {
            myTipText = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.MyTipText, this.Font, brush, e.ClipRectangle.Location);
    }

    internal void AddControl(Component component)
    {
        if (component != null)
        {
            if (component is Control)
            {
                Control control = component as Control;

                control.HandleCreated += control_HandleCreated;

                if (control.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    control_HandleCreated(control, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    void control_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if(control!=null)
        {
            m_tools[control.Handle] = control;

            m_toolInfo.hwnd = this.Handle;
            m_toolInfo.uId = control.Handle;

            **int result = WindowsAPI.SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)TTM.TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, ref m_toolInfo);**
        }
    }

}
```

But the SendMessage results in failure. May i know, why the custom control fails to set as Tooltip for the control.

Here is the SendMessage,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref TOOLINFO lParam);
```

I could not find the reason for failure. Please anyone help me on this.

Regards,
Amal Raj U.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see you WNDProc Method. All messages would be sent to your address. But unless a cather like "WndProc(ref Message m)" and there is no default transmission for your custom messages, they are flying on the air.

```
TTM.TTM_ADDTOOLW
```

This is your custom message will be sent to recepient. There must be a control with overrided WndProc method and this method must catch you message and do your thing there.

I sent a message from Form1 to Form2:

```
`SendMessage(Form2.handle, Msgs.Close, 0, null)`
```

and catched from Form2 like:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == Msgs.Close) {
        AskForExit();
    } else if (m.Msg == Msgs.Other) {
        DoOtherStuffOwnedByMe();
    }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Perhaps it may be lead you a solution.